# How to zipalign a Apk with kivy buildozer?

Tags: android, python, linux, kivy, buildozer

My path is cd ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/build-tools/19.1.0/

the name of my apk is   MyApplication-0.1-release-unsigned.apk

the path of apk is   /home/kivy/Desktop/provaAPP/bin

Answer (score 1):

Something like `~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/build-tools/19.1.0/zipalign -v 4 /home/kivy/Desktop/provaAPP/bin/yourapkname.apk youroutputapkname.apk`, I think.

Comment: Hello and thanks,forgive my little experience,im a beginner  1step is ok ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/build-tools/19.1.0 but the 2step i read  bash: zipalign: command not found ihave replace yourapkname and youroutputname can u help me please

Comment: zipalign -v 4 /home/kivy/Desktop/provaAPP/bin/MyApplication-0.1-release-unsigned.apk                                                                             output MyApplication-0.1-release-unsigned.apk

Comment: I HAVE RESOLVED ./zipalign -v 4 ~/Desktop/provaAPP/bin/MyApplication-0.1-release-unsigned.apk  ~/Desktop/provaAPP/bin/MyApplication-0.1-aligned.apk